# create class and call specific functions - string list

Tags: python

i want to create a StringList class where i can call following functions:

```
s1 = StringList()
s1.strings.append('a string')
```

a string has to be created as a list, and i want to be able to add strings to that list and later print out the string plus the lengths of the string

so far i created the class // thx to the answer i edited it so far

```
 class StringList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.strings = []
        self.lenghts = 0
```

edit: so far i have (thx to comments and solution)

```
class StringList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.strings = []


    def add_string(self, string_value):
        self.strings.append(string_value)
```

which is able to do

```
s1.add_string('a string')
```

now comes my problem with lengths. i cant get it to work.

when using it like this:

```
 class StringList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.strings = []
    def add_string(self, string_value):
        self.strings.append(string_value)
    def lengths(self):
        return len(self.string_value)
```

following shows up

```
>>> s1 = StringList()
>>> s1.add_string('a string')
>>> print(s1.strings, s1.lengths)
['a string'] <bound method StringList.lengths of <__main__.StringList object at 0x03566CB0>>
```

Comment: `def __init__(self, strings, lenghts):` you need to pass the constructor values for `strings` and `lenghts`  (which is misspelled).  Or you can have default values like `def __init__(self, strings=[], lenghts=0):`  Also, there can only be one `StringList.lenghts`. You cannot have both a method of that name and an attribute of that name

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Be careful advising people to use an empty list as a default argument (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: I have the feeling you're still trying to get the grasp on OOP. If you want `s1.strings.append('a string')` then `strings` has to be a `list`. I think what you really want is a method `append` so that you can call `s1.append('a string')`.

Comment: BTW, you are spelling 'lenghts' wrong (should be 'lengths')

Comment: The code for `add_string(self, string_value)` is  `self.strings.append(string_value)`

Comment: Have a read of [this tutorial](http://www.programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_classes&lang=en) to learn about classes, or just find any other tutorial you like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear what you are asking, but here goes:

Is `self.strings` supposed to be a list? As I understand it, `self.strings` is supposed to be a list that you can put stuff in both when you create the class (i.e. parameters) and using `sl.strings.append('a string')`. Is this correct, or do you only want the latter functionality?

If you only want the latter (which I suspect is the case), then quite simply define your class like this:

```
class StringList:
    def __init__(self, lenghts):
        self.strings = []
```

Then you can freely run `sl.strings.append('a string')` to add strings.

If you want the both aforementioned functionalities, then you have do do it like this:

```
class StringList:
    def __init__(self, strings=None, lenghts):
        self.strings = strings if strings is not None else []
```

The default arguments are set up so that if you don't pass a parameter when you create an instance of `StringList`, then it will assign the parameter `[]`. If you do pass something as an argument, it will have to be a list for you to later be able to run `sl.strings.append('a string')`

The `strings=None` default argument is used because using an empty list as a default argument is [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: @mistergreen: I have a feeling you might read the wrong book for learning Python. Which one do you use?

Comment: i am using standard python 3 documentation, but i cant figure it out how to use it for the given task

Comment: @mistergreen I've read your new problem, but you'll have to post the code you are calling for `add_string`.

Comment: If you read the documentation like you read the comments to your question it might take you a while. I wrote the code for the `add_string` method 20 minutes ago in the comments ...

Comment: when adding it like you suggested i get the same error

Comment: @mistergreen The problem you currently have is because you are trying to print `s1.lengths`, which is a method. If you want to print what the method returns, run `print(s1.lenghts())`